# TSQL Extended Procedure 'xp_dirscan'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the equivalent of the extended procedure 'xp_dirscan' in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not native shipped code in SQL Server.
It's a 3rd party extenfed stored proc (which is a DLL).

You can register on [SQL Server Central and see this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administering/sql2000dbatoolkitpart4/2364/) with download and instructions.

It's for SQL 2000 but registering the DLL should be the same (I've not tried it on '2005)

Answer (score 0):

`xp_dirscan` seems to be an extended stored proc that performs a recursive directory search. If you have access to the DLL you could register it as an extended stored proc in SQL 2005.

Alternatively, you could code something that performs the same action using `xp_cmdshell` or a managed extended stored proc.